# How to detect and analyze audio levels

Tags: python, audio, record

I'm trying to write a script that'll listen for my input and print "ON" when it senses that someone is volume, and print "OFF" when it senses that the person has stopped talking.

The following is what I've got so far and it partially works:

```
import collections
import audioop
import pyaudio
import time
import math

CHUNK = 1024 # The size of the chunk to read from the mic stream
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt24 # The format depends on the mic used
CHANNELS = 2 # The number of channels used to record the audio. Depends on the mic
RATE = 44100 # The sample rate for audio. Depends on the mic
THRESHOLD = 6000 # The threshold intensity that defines silence. 
                 # an int lower than THRESHOLD is considered silence 
RECORD_SECONDS=5

def test():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,rate=RATE,input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    q = collections.deque(maxlen=RATE/CHUNK)

    flag = True;
    print("--Listening--")  

    for i in range(0,int(RATE/CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        q.append(abs(audioop.avg(data,4)))


    print(sum(q)/(RATE/CHUNK*RECORD_SECONDS))

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

def listen():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,rate=RATE,input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    q = collections.deque(maxlen=RATE/CHUNK)

    flag = True;
    print("--Listening--")  

    while(True):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        q.append(abs(audioop.avg(data,4)))
        if(flag==True):
            if (sum(q)/(RATE/CHUNK*RECORD_SECONDS)<3500000):
                print("OFF")
                flag=False
        else:
            if(sum(q)/(RATE/CHUNK*RECORD_SECONDS)>3500000):
                print("ON")
                flag=True


if(__name__== '__main__'):
    test()
```

The listen() method is the 'ON' 'OFF' method while test() is to check audio levels.

I'm not entirely sure that the audioop is the right way to do this. After playing with the 'test' method for a few minutes it seems to be inconsistent with the volume level. 
I can get very high values from it (8,000,000) for whispering while getting 4,000,000 for regular talking and 3,000,000 for not talking at all (silence).

Is there a way to make it consistent with audio levels? 
So that I'll get a certain range for silence, a higher one for whispering, a higher one for talking etc (i.e it'll be consistent)?